# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Music: Practice & Theory's [first moderator election](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Dom] [image: Dr Mayhem]   [image: Matthew Read]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/flair/28.png))</sub>

They will be installed as [moderators](https://music.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering. Also, share your assistance and advice as Dom learns the ropes!

Finally, let us thank [NReilingh](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/133/nreilingh) who served as a *pro tempore* moderator and did not run this time around.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6273448686911488/0).

Comment: How about a face, Dom?

Comment: @luserdroog we'll see if I can dig up a picture I like, although I've grown quite attached to the current one.

Answer (score 11):

Although I'm the odd man out, let me be the first to congratulate you guys. We all know the work Matt and Rory have been doing here these past years. I'm really psyched for Dom, because he not only moderates the community the way he was able to, but he provides the site with quality answers and some (imo) of the best questions ([this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16376/1-%E2%88%9A%CF%80-%E2%88%9A%E2%85%94-as-a-time-signature) and [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/25453/why-is-bass-note-so-important-in-harmonic-analysis-of-music))!

Kudos to you all!

Comment: Thanks @Shevliaskovic. Sad to lose NReilingh, but as Shev says, Dom should be a good addition to the team - especially with his link to Music Fans.

Comment: Likewise -- and I'm sure we'll need you as a mod when the site grows!

Comment: Keep doing what you're doing, you're an excellent member of the community and there's always next time. Who knows we may need a fourth sooner than then.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the great work in the past and going forward! Sorry that I'm no longer able to devote the time the job requires, but I'm certainly not going anywhere as far as the site is concerned. :-)

Comment: Thanks for being willing to serve. I am sure your time to take up the mop will come soon!

Answer (score 7):

Well done to the 3 moderators! Commiserations to Shevliaskovic, who would have made a good mod, I think. Pity about the only 15% voters, but that's probably on par for a lot of elections.